# canvas get image pixel point when mouse click event

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas

I use canvas in my project and i set a picture to canvas background, i want when i click in image area i get orginal pixel point
so i want convert canvas cordinate to pixel cordinate

define canvas in typescript:

```
     context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
     @ViewChild( 'myCanvas' ) canvas: ElementRef;
     ngAfterViewInit() {
      const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;
      let context=canvas.getContext( '2d' );
      var background = new Image();
      background.src = "assets/media/products/1.png";
      background.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

      background.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(background,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
      this.context= context
      this.cdr.detectChanges()
     
    }
```

and show canvas in html :

```
 <canvas #myCanvas id="canvas"  (click)="clickPosition($event)"></canvas>
```

```
    clickPosition(event: MouseEvent) {
      console.log("X  = " + event.offsetX);
      console.log("Y = " + event.offsetY);
    }
```

event.offsetX show cordinate screen size but i want get image pixel, for this problem i use getImageData()
but i dont recive correct data

Answer (score 0):

Try this function - element.getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: i want getting pixel codinate (x,y) of canvas image, ths function for other work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).